# Many clients trying to write in a CSV file

Tags: php, csv, append, fopen

With the following code:

```
<?php
...
if (isset($_POST['id']))
{
    $out = fopen('test.csv', 'a');
    fputcsv($out, array($_POST['id'], $uid, $time, $_POST['name']));
    fclose($out);
}
?>
```

what would happen if many clients (e.g. 10 or 100 per seconds on average) connect the server at the same time?

Is there a risk of loosing some of the clients' input (this is ok, not a big deal in case of CPU 100% usage, I prefer this than crashing the server), **or worse, have a bad open/close/open/close/open/close (twice at the same time) erasing the file, thus causing a lost of past data**?

It's just for a simple logging, I'd like to avoid to setup a MySql server for this.

Comment: Don't you think each CSV file should be unique? with a unique filename like   `'test_' . time() . '.csv'`. You won't risk to have people overriding other people's file

Comment: @SamHecquet it's like a log file, it should be one unique file

Comment: okay so nevermind :)

Answer (score 1):

You might lose data if the size of the data you append to the file is too large.

POSIX appends are atomic (meaning they will start and complete without being overwritten by another process) if the size of data appended is less than a certain amount. On Linux this is 4012 bytes. When a process is trying to write over 4012 bytes, it might overwrite whatever processes are also trying to write to the file.

If you can guarantee that all of your data combined (plus the commas, quotes, and newlines CSV requires) adds up to less than 4012 bytes per entry, you'll be OK.  That means you will need to do strict data validation.

You can ensure that there will be no overwriting by using [`flock()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) to lock the file so that only one process will write at a time:

```
$out = fopen('test.csv', 'a');

$tries = 5;
while ($tries > 0) {
    $locked = flock($out,LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB);
    if (! $locked) {
        usleep(10000);
        $tries--;
    } else {
        $tries = 0;
    }
}

if ($locked) {
    // If you got the lock, write and unlock.
    fputcsv($out, array($_POST['id'], $uid, $time, $_POST['name']));
    flock($out,LOCK_UN);
} else {
    // Do whatever if you didn't get the lock.
}

fclose($out);
```

Comment: Thanks! So something like `$out = fopen('test.csv', 'a'); flock($out); fputcsv($out, array($_POST['id'], $uid, $time, $_POST['name'])); fclose($out);`?

Comment: Something like that, though you will probably want to retry if you can't get the lock. See my edited answer. Also, it might be easier to use something like [SQLite](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_php.htm), which won't require any setup outside of your PHP and will handle all of this and more automatically.